# Flipping binary string python3

Tags: python

How can I flip binary strings in python3?

If I have 001011, it should output 110100.

I want to define it `def flip(binary_string)`

here is what I've tried:

```
def flip(binary_string):
  for bit in binary_string:
    if bit == "1":
      "1" == "0"
    else:
      "0" == 1
    return binary_string
```

Answer (score 0):

This code checks every character in the string and converts the 0s to 1s and vice versa:

```py
def flip(binary_string):
    value = ""
    for bit in binary_string: value.join("1" if bit == "0" else "0")
    return value

print(flip("10110"))
```

Comment: a verbal explanation is often helpful

Answer (score 0):

You could make the characters into integers and then into strings again like this:

```
string = "0001010011110"

def flip(bstring):
    return "".join(str((int(c)+1)%2) for c in bstring)

flip(string)  # '1110101100001'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def flip(binary_str):    
    return ''.join('0' if i == '1' else '1' for i in binary_str)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.